# How to enable/disable an App Widgets in Android based on sdk version?

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to implement a widget that uses Stackview which is supported on sdk 11 and higher.  My app uses sdk 8, so can I enable/disable a widget based on the sdk version?

Comment: I use :`if(Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK)>=11)`

Comment: @Sherif, please read the question properly first instead of giving me some generic answer like this.  I know you can use 'Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK)>=11' but how does this help me with what I am trying to achieve in any way?

Comment: Really? ok I will read well next time. Check this : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html

Comment: 1 more thing, you set the minSDK to 8 and the targetSDK to 11. and inside the program check using the android.os.build.version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the app widget is to be totally unavailable, mark the `<receiver>` as disabled in the manifest (`android:enabled="false"`). Then, on first run of your app, check your version and conditionally enable the app widget via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. The only downside is that your app widget will not show up as available until they launch your app for the first time.

If the app widget is simply to have different behavior on different versions, use `res/layout-v11/` for your `StackView` implementation and `res/layout/` for your non-`StackView` implementation. Your `AppWidgetProvider` can check the API level and configure the `RemoteViews` and related stuff accordingly.

Comment: You can handle this completely via xml with a bool xml resource. Set `android:enabled="@bool/stackViewAllowed"`. Create a xml resource `/values/bools.xml` with `<bool name="stackViewAllowed">false</bool>` and a resource `/values-v11/bools.xml` with `<bool name="stackViewAllowed">true</bool>` Then it will be enabled for honeycomb (11) and upwards and disabled before.

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty: Excellent point, though I think your approach only handles my first paragraph, not the second. I'm just mentioning that for anyone coming across this answer and your comment in the future. Thanks for adding this!

Answer (score 7):

Make a xml bools.xml  in res\values folder and add the below line

**res\values**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
<bool name="widgetenable">false</bool> 
</resources>
```

and like the same way add bool.xml in values-v11 folder also just replace widgetenable to ture like this

**res\values-v11**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
<bool name="widgetenable">true</bool> 
</resources>
```

and after that in your manisfest.xml on the widget recever tag add this line

```
android:enabled="@bool/widgetenable"
```

This will enable or disable widget based on the sdk.